# SQL Inner Join on a single table, between two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

Kinda new to SQL but I have a table with employees and date ranges.
I need to List employees who had a salary increase between 01/01/2006 and 05/31/2006. Its only in one table and according to instructions I'm supposed to use an Inner Join somewhere.

This is what I have now

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateLast
FROM tblEmployees
WHERE (DateLast>=#01/01/2006#) AND (DateLast>=#05/31/2006#);
```

What am I doing wrong? Where does the Inner Join fit in here?

Thanks

Comment: An inner join is only for joining two tables together.  If you have all the data in one table, a join is not needed.  Where is the increase noted?

Comment: also your greater than or equal in second test should probbaly be a less then or equal to

Comment: As it stands, you don't need an inner join.  Check the wording of the question - perhaps it's required for something else; e.g. maybe another table with additional info which needs to be included in your results?

Answer (score 0):

In ur case u can get results in two ways

```
where datecolumn between startdate and   endate
```

or

```
where datecolumn >= startdate and date column <= endate
```